# Jenkins Cucumber report send as an Email attachment

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm able to generate the HTML report for cucumber on Jenkins.But I would like to know if there is any way to convert that HTML to pdf as a post build action or send the HTML report without losing any format.
I'm able to send the HTML report to email but it's not formatted.It is missing the folder structure.
Plugin I'm using as post build action is Editable Email Notification and in Attachments I give this *, js/*,fonts/*,embeddings/*,css/* .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've done this a while ago via 3th party service. You can use this [htmlpdf](http://www.htmlpdf.com/) site and send a request with form-data URL parameter  (or there is stand-alone app as well) or this [html2pdfrocket API](https://www.html2pdfrocket.com/).

In case you are looking just for the content as image, you can create dedicated build step using [Selenium's screenshot](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) option and add it as attachment in the email body.